# ReferenceError: Response is not defined

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

**Short Version:**

I am writing a test case for my Vue component using `vue-test-utils` and  `jest`.

I am trying to create a `Response` object in one of my test cases, but I keep getting error 
`ReferenceError: Response is not defined`

**Long Version**

I am trying to mock an API response when a Vuex action is dispatched using jest.
I have created a Vuex action like this

```
let fakeAccountList = [
  {"id":"abcd","title":"Random Account 1"},
  {"id":"pqrs","title":"Random Account 2"}
]
actions = {
   getAccounts: jest.fn(()=>{

     return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       resolve(mockResponse(200,'ok',fakeAccountList))
      })
    })
 }
```

The `getAccounts` action returns a Promise which resolves to a list of accounts. The `mockResponse` function is as shown:

```
mockResponse = (status, statusText, response) => {

  return new Response(response, {
    status: status,
    statusText: statusText,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
};
```

When `mockResponse` is called, I get the error `ReferenceError: Response is not defined`

I found this very old issue:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/930
The comments suggest that it was fixed,but, it is not working for me. I do not want to import extra libraries such as `isomorphic-fetch` just for this.

Here is my `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "3.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "3.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.0.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.25",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "less": "3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "4.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "node-sass": "4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "7.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.16",
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using a react application and just adding the below statement in your mock file resolved the issue. Hope this might be helpful for you or others.

`import 'isomorphic-fetch'`

Comment: This worked for me.  I had similar concerns to OP. I didn't want to add a whole new library just to make a test work when the production code had been working for a while. Turns out `isomorphic-fetch` was a transitive dependency my code already had.

Comment: isomorphic-fetch does not implement Response.error()

Answer (score 0):

`isomorphic-fetch` does not implement `Response.error()` . So I use `whatwg-fetch`

Here's a test that shows it working.  I use `fetch-mock-jest` for the fetch mocking.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock-jest';
describe('http', () => {
  let fetchConfigResponse: (new () => Response) | undefined;
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchConfigResponse = fetchMock.config.Response;
    jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    fetchMock.mockReset();
    fetchMock.config.Response = fetchConfigResponse;
  });

  it('Simple fetch example', async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'));
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net', { body: { hello: 'world' } });
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net');
    expect(Date.now()).toBe(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z').getTime());
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(await response.json()).toStrictEqual({ hello: 'world' });
  });
  it('Non-JSON json() call', async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'));
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net', { body: 'not a json' });
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net');
    expect(Date.now()).toBe(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z').getTime());
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    try {
      await response.json();
      fail('should not get here');
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e instanceof Error).toBeTruthy();
    }
  });

  it('Error example', async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'));
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net/bad-request', {
      status: 400,
      body: { bad: 'request' },
    });
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net/bad-request');
    expect(Date.now()).toBe(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z').getTime());
    expect(response.status).toBe(400);
    expect(response.ok).toBe(false);
    expect(await response.json()).toStrictEqual({ bad: 'request' });
  });

  it('401 Error example', async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'));
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net/bad-request', {
      status: 401,
      body: { bad: 'request' },
    });
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net/bad-request');
    expect(Date.now()).toBe(new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z').getTime());
    expect(response.status).toBe(401);
    expect(response.ok).toBe(false);
    expect(await response.json()).toStrictEqual({ bad: 'request' });
  });

  it('should work with Response.error()', async () => {
    fetchMock.config.Response = Response;
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net/bad-request', Response.error());
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net/bad-request');
    expect(response.status).toBe(0);
  });
  it('should work with global.Response.error()', async () => {
    fetchMock.config.Response = global.Response;
    fetchMock.mock('https://trajano.net/bad-request', global.Response.error());
    const response = await fetch('https://trajano.net/bad-request');
    expect(response.status).toBe(0);
  });
  it('Response.error type check', async () => {
    fetchMock.config.Response = Response;
    expect(Response.error() instanceof Response).toBe(true);
    expect(
      fetchMock.config.Response?.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Response.error())
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Another approach but I don't normally do so I have better control of the tests is to add it to `jestConfig.setupFiles` as

```
require('whatwg-fetch');
```